# Angular material missing buttons styling

Tags: angular, angular-material

Just started to learn Angular material and immediately stuck with buttons styling problem.

I've added MatButtonModule to my app.

**Module's code**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { View1Component } from './view1/view1.component';
import { View2Component } from './view2/view2.component';
import { View3Component } from './view3/view3.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [View1Component, View2Component, View3Component],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, MatButtonModule
  ]
})
export class HeaderModule { }
```

Added the markup to the template.
**Template**

```
<p>view2 works!</p>

<button mat-button color="primary">Angular Material Button</button><br/><br>
<button mat-raised-button>Raised button</button><br><br>
<button mat-flat-button>Flat button</button><br><br>
<button mat-stroked-button>Stroked button</button><br><br>
<button mat-icon-button>Icon button</button><br><br>
<button mat-fab>Fab button</button><br><br>
<button mat-mini-fab>Mini Fab button</button><br><br>
```

But got strange looking result:
[Rendering result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuqFg.png)

Checked in different browsers, tried the simmilar code in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-osm5of) - and got the same result... but expected the buttons to be styled something like [this](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview)

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The pink theme was added automatically to "angular.json" with the use of Angular CLI when I installed "@angular/material" library.

```
...
"styles": [
 "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
 "src/styles.css"
 ],
...
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've added the following to the styles.css as was suggested and it works!

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Howerver it is still not clear why the imports in "angular.json" didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible there's a missing import in `styles.css`:

```css
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Comment: I've added the import you've mentioned and it works!  but still don't understand why it didn't work before as the pink theme was added automatically to "angular.json" with the use of Angular CLI when I installed "@angular/material" library... `"styles": [
 "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
 "src/styles.css"
 ],`

Comment: @DmitriiMeico, are you using CSS or SASS / SCSS in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because of two things.

1. you are missing a Material theme: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

you can add one by importing a Material theme to your root SCSS file. styles files.
or
declaring one in the angular.json file under styles.

2. Also try adding color attribute to the remaining of the buttons once you have your theme in place.

Comment: Yeap it was the problem with theme imports. Thank you!